# Why does MATLAB solve not solve a linear equation?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do a basic linear equation using the symbolic toolbox. I set my equation, two initial conditions, and solve, but I only get an empty result:

```
syms y(x) x m c

eqn = y(x) == m*x + c;
cond1 = y(x==0) == 0;
cond2 = y(x==1) == 1;
sol = solve(eqn,cond1,cond2,m,c)
```

It returns sol.c as 0 but sol.m as `y(x)/x`

Comment: It is a valid result, I guess. Except in 0. I do not know matlab's symbolic that well, but the fact that your conditions allow for this solution might be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could transform your conditions into vectors:

```
a = [0;1];
b = [0;1];

syms m c
eqn =  a.*m + c -b ==0;
sol = solve(eqn,m,c)
```

This will result in a scalar value for m